# Removing Google Protocol Buffers Error Strings From Binary

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have been playing with Google Protocol Buffers lately and have created a sample application with them.

When I run strings on my final binary, I see a lot of Google Protocol Buffers strings.  Upon further investigation, there are a lot of calls to `GOOGLE_LOG`, `GOOGLE_LOG_IF`, and other Google macros that are ultimately overloading the stream operator.  These strings are all error messages that I do not want in my binary (and do not appear to be needed for Google Protocol Buffers to work correctly).

Does anyone know an easy way to disable these strings from appears other than going through all the Google Protocol Buffers source and removing the error messages?

Comment: What language are you compiling into? Did you try the options `option optimize_for = CODE_SIZE;` and/or `option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;`? They might help. If it doesn't work you can still open an enhancement request to Google :)

Comment: I guess it would help if I included that information!  I am compiling for C++ and I am using `option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;` in my `.proto` source file.  I think an enhancement request may be in order.  Thanks!